# How can the conditional expectation be the $L^2$ projection, when the $L^2$ projection depends on the choice of the norm?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, projection

one can define the conditional expectation of a random variable $X$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ in an axiomatic way, without relying on any norm by being the $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variable $Y$ which fulfills
$$\mathbb{E}[Y 1_A] = \mathbb{E}[X 1_A]$$
for any $A \in \mathcal{G}$.

However, one can also define it as the $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ projection onto all $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variables, where $\mathbb{P}$ is the distribution of $X$. But this projection is defined by minimizing
$$\mathbb{E}[\|X - Y\|^2]$$
and therefore depends on the choice of norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. How can that be?

Or to phrase it more generally, if I have the conditional expectation on some topological space, where I do not have such a natural norm as in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with respect to which norm will it be the $L^2$ projection?

Comment: Does anything go wrong if you just project one component at a time? (This is basically a question about whether "project then take the ith component" is the same as "project the ith component ").

Comment: I may be wrong, but from what I remember, the norm in this case is just the standard Euclidian norm. For other norms, the equivalence of definition does not hold.

Comment: @Ian, projecting one component at a time needs the choice of components and basically assumes that these components are an ONB. Therefore it includes choosing an ONB or equivalently, a scalar product/norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, I think this just shifts the problem. The projection will depend on the choice of "components"/the ONB.

Comment: Among norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying the parallelogram identity, does the result of the minimization actually depend on the norm? (I think in other norms you don't even have a Hilbert space anymore so that is a non-starter.) I wouldn't be surprised to hear it does but that seems worth checking.